# EXCEL Formula_use AGGREGATE function as MIN but meet error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use `AGGREGATE` function as MIN to choose the largest and the smallest number in one column. Because `AGGREGATE` can also ignore the `DIV/0` during this progress.

```
Apple1 | weight | 1.2
Apple1 | height | 0.5
Apple1 | price  | 1
Apple2 | weight | DIV/0
Apple2 | height | 1.1
Apple2 | price  | 1
Apple3 | weight | 1.1
Apple3 | height | 0.8
Apple3 | price  | 1
```

And here is my code:

```
=AGGREGATE(15;3;(B1:B9="weight")*(C1:C9);1)
```

But when I try to use `MIN` to choose the smallest in the positive results or use `MAX` to choose the biggest in the negative results, the search result is always 0 but not the "correct" one. In the example above, it should be 1.1, but it gives me 0.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry I didn't not all understand your comment. So you mean that this is out of the capability of AGGREGATE function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `AGGREGATE`, only a *function* parameter of 14 or greater is compatible with an *array* parameter which is not a worksheet range (or else some construction which resolves to a worksheet range).

However, since the combination of *function* parameter 15 (`SMALL`) with *k* parameter 1 is equivalent to finding the minimum, you should employ this version, viz:

`=AGGREGATE(15;3;C1:C9/(B1:B9="weight");1)`

Regards

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this laterly, ans tell you more details about that!

Comment: @Hiddenllyy The reason for this is you chose option 3 which includes ignore errors.  In your formula in you question, when a value is not equal to "weight" it is false and excel treats it as a value of 0.  Anything multiplied by 0 is 0, so 0 is your smallest positive number/largest negative number.  With XOR LX's formula, when you are dealing with something that is not in your criteria ("weight"), you wind up trying to divide by 0 which causes an error.  And since you chose option 3, the error is ignored, and you are left with only values from your range in column C which meet your criteria.